# Clarification on accessing methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I am having trouble accessing a method i have written in a class, the problem is im trying to access it within an instance of that class, but would appreciate someone explain in a bit more details as to why this doesn't work and things to look at to get a solution.

I have created a simple helper method to use in my view to join two attributes

```
class TeamMember < ActiveRecord::Base

  def fullname
    "#{self.forename} #{self.surname}"
  end
end
```

Within my view (show action) I want to be able to use this method

```
def show
  @team_member = TeamMember.find(params[:id])
end
```

So doing this for example gives me an undefined method

```
<%= link_to fullname(@team_member) %>
OR
<% @team_member.each do |t| %>
  <%= link_to fullname, t %>
<% end %>
```

Whereas this works

```
<% @team_member.each do |t| %>
  <%= link_to "#{t.forename} #{t.surname}", t %>
<% end %>
```

Could someone help to clarify this for me so that i can learn from it please

Comment: not `link_to fullname(@team_member)` try this `link_to @team_member.fullname` and `<%= link_to t.fullname, t %>` if this work i can explain in answer.

Comment: You defined `fullname` as a no argument method, but you are passing arguments.

Comment: @Monk_Code Go ahead... That's the reason.

Comment: @Monk_Code <%= link_to t.fullname, t %> works..if you could explain in a nice and simple way that would be great :)  why two uses of t is my first question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `fullname` method in your `TeamMember` class, but you try to call this method with implicit receiver in view, which is `ActionView::Base` instance. Instead, you should use explicit receiver, which must be `TeamMember` instance:

```
<%= link_to @team_member.fullname, @team_member %>
```

and:

```
<%= link_to t.fullname, t %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation..So the main issue here was that I tried to call a class method within an instance of that class, and to access that method i needed to explicitly use that instance on the method ?

Comment: @Richlewis the main issue was that you were trying to call instance method on instance of another class. 
`TeamMember#fullname` is `TeamMember` instance method, but you were trying to call it on `ActionView::Base` instance, instead of `TeamMember` instance (because `ActionView::Base` instance is implicit receiver in views).

Comment: sorry another question...what object would be the ActionView::Base instance in this case?

Comment: @Richlewis it's the object referenced by `self` in your view code.